# Replace string separated with comma

Tags: php, string, replace

Is there any way to change or convert a strings/int that are separated with commas?

Example :

$str = "121,232,343,454";

should result into :

str1, str1, str1, str1

Comment: u mean the result should be , str1=121, str2=232, str=343 like this

Comment: Your example makes no sense to me. Could you explain what you've tried, the results you got, and maybe add a second example?

Comment: First, what programming language are you using?

Comment: I am using PHP, what I want supposed to be displayed is the same result each word/integer separated by comma.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the language you are using, this is often the `split($str, ',')` or `split(',', $str)` or `$str.split(',')` function

Answer (score 2):

split() is deprecated !!! Please use explode($seperator, $string) instead.

```
$str = "a,b,c";
$items = explode(',', $str);
```